# Degree of an exclusionary Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let's say I've got a field $\mathbb{Q}[i]$\ $\mathbb{Q}$. What's the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}[i]$\ $\mathbb{Q}$ : $\mathbb{Q}$? Clearly without the exclusion this has a degree of 2; since the degree of any field extension is an integer, I'd posit that the degree of the above field extension is also 2.

Comment: $\Bbb Q [i] \setminus \Bbb Q$ is NOT  field. For example, it is not closed under multiplication: $i \cdot i = -1 \in \Bbb Q$

Comment: In particular, $i\times i = -1$..

Comment: and $\mathbb Q[i]$ without $\mathbb Q$ does not have $0$ and $1$